Cannot connect to postgreSQL database using Ktor
I have an example ktor application where I want to test PostgreSQL connection. Cannot find points where I missed. Docker compose file is ok, container is up. When I run locally getting an error. It seems the problem is about application.yml but not sure.
build.gradle
dependencies {
    implementation "io.ktor:ktor-server-core-jvm"
    implementation "io.ktor:ktor-server-netty-jvm"
    implementation "ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:$logback_version"
    implementation "io.ktor:ktor-server-config-yaml"
    testImplementation "io.ktor:ktor-server-tests-jvm"
    testImplementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit:$kotlin_version"

    implementation "org.jetbrains.exposed:exposed-core:0.50.1"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.exposed:exposed-dao:0.50.1"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.exposed:exposed-jdbc:0.50.1"
    implementation "com.zaxxer:HikariCP:4.0.3"
    implementation 'org.postgresql:postgresql:42.1.4'
}

docker-compose.yml
version: '3.7'

services:
  database:
    image: postgres:14-alpine
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=123456
      - POSTGRES_USER=user
      - POSTGRES_DB=project1
    expose:
      - "5432"

application.yml
ktor:
    application:
        modules:
            - com.activity.ApplicationKt.module
    deployment:
        port: 8080
    database:
        url:
            -jdbc:postgresql://database:5432/project1
        driver:
            -org.postgresql.Driver
        username:
            -user
        password:
            -123456

EXCEPTION
Exception in thread "main" net.mamoe.yamlkt.YamlDecodingException: Top-level decoder: deserializing nested class for '1' in 'kotlin.collections.LinkedHashMap'
        username:
                ^ at line 12, column 18

    at net.mamoe.yamlkt.internal.YamlUtils__ContextualExceptionKt.contextualDecodingException(ContextualException.kt:165)
    at net.mamoe.yamlkt.internal.YamlUtils.contextualDecodingException(Unknown Source)
    at net.mamoe.yamlkt.internal.YamlDecoder$AbstractDecoder.decodeSerializableElement(YamlDecoder.kt:206)
    at kotlinx.serialization.encoding.CompositeDecoder$DefaultImpls.decodeSerializableElement$default(Decoding.kt:533)
    at kotlinx.serialization.internal.MapLikeSerializer.readElement(CollectionSerializers.kt:111)
    at kotlinx.serialization.internal.MapLikeSerializer.readElement(CollectionSerializers.kt:84)
    at kotlinx.serialization.internal.AbstractCollectionSerializer.readElement$default(CollectionSerializers.kt:51)
    at kotlinx.serialization.internal.AbstractCollectionSerializer.merge(CollectionSerializers.kt:36)
    at kotlinx.serialization.internal.AbstractCollectionSerializer.deserialize(CollectionSerializers.kt:43)
    at net.mamoe.yamlkt.internal.YamlElementMapSerializer.deserialize(YamlElementSerializer.kt)
    at net.mamoe.yamlkt.internal.YamlElementSerializer.deserialize(YamlElementSerializer.kt:40)
    at net.mamoe.yamlkt.internal.YamlElementSerializer.deserialize(YamlElementSerializer.kt:30)
    at net.mamoe.yamlkt.Yaml.decodeFromString(Yaml.kt:162)
    at net.mamoe.yamlkt.Yaml.decodeYamlFromString(Yaml.kt:175)
    at io.ktor.server.config.yaml.YamlConfigJvmKt.configFromString(YamlConfigJvm.kt:36)
    at io.ktor.server.config.yaml.YamlConfigJvmKt.YamlConfig(YamlConfigJvm.kt:25)
    at io.ktor.server.config.yaml.YamlConfigLoader.load(YamlConfig.kt:21)
    at io.ktor.server.config.ConfigLoader$Companion.load(ConfigLoaders.kt:33)
    at io.ktor.server.config.ConfigLoader$Companion.load$default(ConfigLoaders.kt:26)
    at io.ktor.server.engine.CommandLineKt.buildApplicationConfig(CommandLine.kt:112)
    at io.ktor.server.engine.CommandLineKt.buildCommandLineEnvironment(CommandLine.kt:33)
    at io.ktor.server.engine.CommandLineKt.commandLineEnvironment(CommandLine.kt:98)
    at io.ktor.server.netty.EngineMain.main(EngineMain.kt:20)
    at com.activity.ApplicationKt.main(Application.kt:7)
Caused by: net.mamoe.yamlkt.YamlDecodingException: Top-level decoder: deserializing nested class for '5' in 'kotlin.collections.LinkedHashMap'
...          -org.postgresql.Driver
                                  ^ at line 11, column 35

    at net.mamoe.yamlkt.internal.YamlUtils__ContextualExceptionKt.contextualDecodingException(ContextualException.kt:165)
    at net.mamoe.yamlkt.internal.YamlUtils.contextualDecodingException(Unknown Source)
    at net.mamoe.yamlkt.internal.YamlDecoder$AbstractDecoder.decodeSerializableElement(YamlDecoder.kt:206)
    at kotlinx.serialization.encoding.CompositeDecoder$DefaultImpls.decodeSerializableElement$default(Decoding.kt:533)
    at kotlinx.serialization.internal.MapLikeSerializer.readElement(CollectionSerializers.kt:111)
    at kotlinx.serialization.internal.MapLikeSerializer.readElement(CollectionSerializers.kt:84)
    at kotlinx.serialization.internal.AbstractCollectionSerializer.readElement$default(CollectionSerializers.kt:51)
    at kotlinx.serialization.internal.AbstractCollectionSerializer.merge(CollectionSerializers.kt:36)
    at kotlinx.serialization.internal.AbstractCollectionSerializer.deserialize(CollectionSerializers.kt:43)
    at net.mamoe.yamlkt.internal.YamlElementMapSerializer.deserialize(YamlElementSerializer.kt)
    at net.mamoe.yamlkt.internal.YamlElementSerializer.deserialize(YamlElementSerializer.kt:40)
    at net.mamoe.yamlkt.internal.YamlElementSerializer.deserialize(YamlElementSerializer.kt:30)
    at net.mamoe.yamlkt.internal.YamlDecoder$AbstractDecoder.decodeSerializableElement(YamlDecoder.kt:204)
        ... 21 more
    Caused by: net.mamoe.yamlkt.YamlDecodingException: Top-level decoder: deserializing nested class for '1' in 'kotlin.collections.LinkedHashMap'
            driver:
                  ^ at line 10, column 16
.......


Looks like the parser is unhappy with your YAML file. It probably contains errors. Or perhaps that's its way to complain that the class cannot be found on the class path.

@LaurenzAlbe yes I think so. Any idea for fixing it?

I think, your yaml keys are wrong for the database connection:
application.yml
ktor:
    application:
        modules:
            - com.activity.ApplicationKt.module
    deployment:
        port: 8080
    database:
        url: "jdbc:postgresql://database:5432/project1"
        driverClass: "org.postgresql.Driver"
        user: "user"
        password: "123456"

You can also omit the list formatting - as you only have one value. I have changed the values to normal strings.
